# Spring's JdbcTemplate with IN Clause Query

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm having a trouble using `Jdbctemplate`'s query method while passing the variable `QUERY` as a query parameter. The following example takes ids as a single parameter and not an array. What's wrong with this code? I've seen some of the examples on the internet which were done in this way and worked just fine. I'm getting the following error: **Parameter "#2" is not set; SQL statement:**

```
  private static final String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE id IN(%s)";
  Long[] ids = getIds();
  String inSql = String.join(",", Collections.nCopies(ids.length, "?"));
  var item = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(String.format(QUERY, inSql),
      new Object[] {ids},
      getBookRowMapper());
```

Comment: Why do you think something's wrong with that code?

Comment: This gives me the error - Parameter "#2" is not set; SQL statement:

Comment: You're passing your parameter array inside an array, just pass `ids` directly.

Comment: still the same problem with queryForObject(String.format(QUERY, inSql),
getBookRowMapper(), ids);

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html).

Using [`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate#queryForObject`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-) you can pass a map of parameters which also supports `List` as a parameter type for use in calluses like `IN`

So you do something as below.

```java
private static final String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE id IN(:ids)";
List<Long> ids = Arrays.asList(getIds());
Map namedParameters = Collections.singletonMap("ids", ids);
var item = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(QUERY,namedParameters,getBookRowMapper())
```